# Is time.sleep() a CPU bound operation?

Tags: python, sleep

I've recently read in [this asyncio article](https://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/python-asyncio/)

> time.sleep() is a CPU bound operation

I usually connected with "CPU bound" that the CPU is actually doing something. So if one has `time.sleep(60)` in a program (A) and then executes

```
A: Gets 1 second
B: Gets 59 seconds (uninterrupted)
A: Finished or not?
```

I always thought about timers being IO. Is that wrong? Or are timers just something special, so that they don't fit into the "IO-bound" / "CPU bound" schema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not. That article is misusing terminology.

A CPU-bound operation is one whose speed is limited by the speed of CPU execution, as opposed to the speed of memory access or network round trips or some other factor. `time.sleep` is not such an operation. A faster CPU does not make `time.sleep` any faster.

Comment: I see your reasoning and it goes in line with mine. But is time.sleep I/O bound?

Comment: @MartinThoma: No. Performing I/O faster will not make `time.sleep` faster either.

Comment: So time.sleep is neither I/O nor CPU bound (but time-bound ). Makes sense to me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Martin Thoma

No, it isn't CPU Bound.

[Document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) Says.

You can also found similar information from here [is a time sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075788/python-is-time-sleepn-cpu-intensive)